# Find data file in Zip file using microcontroller

Tags: zip, microcontroller

I need a microcontroller to read a data file that's been stored in a Zip file (actually a custom [OPC-based](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163372.aspx) file format, but that's irrelevant). The data file has a known name, path, and size, and is guaranteed to be stored uncompressed. What is the simplest & fastest way to find the start of the file data within the Zip file without writing a complete Zip parser?

NOTE: I'm aware of the Zip comment section, but the data file in question is too big to fit in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a simple parser that finds the file data in question using the central directory.